# Is there a way to provide a syntax hint for code within a blockquote?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting, markdown-rendering

Hints like

```
<!-- language: lang-perl -->
```

work fine with top-level code blocks, but there seems to be no way to influence the rendering of code posted within blockquotes

I realise that this probably means that there isn't a way, but I thought it was worth asking the question as Stack Overflow has repeatedly surprised me with arcane techniques

I have resorted to using

```
<!-- language-all: lang-none -->
```

before the blockquote, but that restricts me to only one syntax per blockquote, and also needs resetting at the end of the blockquote to restore the default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to specify the language of individual code blocks within blockquotes. You do this by specifying the hint as part of the blockquote. For example:

```
> Hello World in Perl:

> <!-- language: lang-perl -->

>     print "Hello world!";
```

Result:

> Hello World in Perl:
>
> ```perl
> print "Hello world!";
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I was sure I'd tried every combination, but seemingly not this one. So simple